# How to create XML in the style used in an OpenOffice document

Tags: .net, xml

I need to create some XML in the following style:

```
  <text:p>One</text:p>
  <text:p>two
    <text:span>three
      <text:line-break/>four
      <text:line-break/>five
      <text:line-break/>six
    </text:span>seven
  </text:p>
  <text:p>eight</text:p>
```

but I can't work out how to add the text and line-break nodes next to each other. Using .NET XML classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is to set the InnerXml property of the text:span node, making sure to have appended it to the document first so that it doesn't complain about undeclared namespaces.